# BehaviorSubject from switchMap then getValue is not a function error

Tags: angular, rxjs, typescript-typings, behaviorsubject, switchmap

this is my class ts code

```
this.product$ = <BehaviorSubject<Product>>this.route.params.switchMap(
  (params): BehaviorSubject<Product> =>
   this.productService.getProduct(params['_id'])
);
```

this is code from service

```
  getProduct(_id: string): BehaviorSubject<Product> {
    const bs = new BehaviorSubject<Product>
                   (ProductService.initializeProduct());
    if (_id !== '0') {
      this.productSub = this.databaseService.getProduct(_id).subscribe(
        product => {
        bs.next(product);
        }
      );
    }
    return bs;
  }
```

I declare type, and also cast type, but yet when I write

```
console.log(product$.getValue)
```

I get this error:

ERROR TypeError: this.product$.getValue is not a function

thanks

Answer (score 3):

That isn't how `switchMap` - and RxJS, in general - works. The observable returned by an operator depends upon the observable upon which the operator is called. Said observable can implement [`lift`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/60) to return an observable instance of the same type.

The result of your call to `switchMap` will be lifted from the `this.route.params` observable. It's not a `BehaviorSubject` and does not have a `getValue` method.

Comment: You can't do what you appear to want to do in the snippet. And the code in your question is all there is to go on. Extrapolating from the code, it looks like you are attempting access something synchronously and that is not possible.

Comment: that's correct, I'm trying to get value synchronously, and this is possible with BehaviorSubject, my only problem is that I couldn't return BehavorSubject from swichmap. I want to escape the nested code in subscribe and enjoy the elegance of switchmap.

Comment: It's not possible because the `this.route.params` observable and the observable returned by `this.databaseService.getProduct` are almost certainly not synchronous. You will have to deal with the asynchronicity.